# How can perform date operation on Text type field in Apache Solr query?

Tags: solr, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, solrcloud, solrnet

I have Solr schema with 'create_date' field type **class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField** in table (**mydb.mytable_copy1**)

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="create_date" stored="true" type="TextField" docValues="true"/>
```

Cassandra table (**mydb.mytable_copy1**) have text data type for '**create_date**' column (*create_date text*)

I would like to perform date operation on Solr query:

> SELECT * from mydb.mytable_copy1 WHERE solr_query =
>   '{"q":"update_date:*","facet":{"range":"update_date",
>   "f.update_date.range.start":"2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
>   "f.update_date.range.end":"2018-08-01T00:00:00Z",
>   "f.update_date.range.gap":"+7DAY"},"useFieldCache":true}';

I am getting below error:

[image]

Can any one please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: To perform date operations (and specifically date range faceting), the field has to be indexed as a date. I'm not familiar with the Cassandra integration, but you'll have to find a way to change the field type to date on the Solr side. Text and date fields are indexed and processed differently.

Comment: Alternatively, if can't or don't want to change this field you could create a second (indexed, non stored, multiValue=false) of type date and add a copyField so that it gets copied from create_date to this new field and you can range search on it. Of course, this will increase the index size so see if it is worth doing. A schema change, core reloading  and reindexing will be required.